# Consider the operator $T:L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^2(0,1)$. Is it well defined, linear, bounded, compact?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, functional-calculus

I'm studying Funtional Analysis and I'm doing some exercise, but I haven't got any idea how to start this.

Consider the operator $T:L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^2(0,1)$ given by
$$(Tu)(x):=\int_0^1(x^2+3x+1)u(y)\ dy$$

Is it well defined, linear, bounded, compact?

My first idea is to get out the $p(x)$ from the integral being in $dy$, so it becomes

$$(x^2+3x+1)\int_0^1u(y)\ dy$$

but I don't think I can do something like that, right? Someone could help me?

Comment: $C^0$ and $L^2$ are not quite the same.

Comment: Yeah, sorry man I've corrected

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by $|_0^1$ - the $p(x)$ is just a multiplicative constant, you don't integrate it.

Comment: Yeah you're right

Comment: Study the linear functional $u\mapsto \int_0^1 u(y)\,dy$ first. Is it well defined, linear, bounded?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with $f=u$, $g=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{0}^{1}|Tu(x)|^2 = \int_{0}^{1}(x^2 +3x+1)^2 dx (\int_{0}^{1}u)^2dy\leq C ||u||^2$ by Jensen's inequality . Therefore $T$ is well-defined and bounded.For compactness let $||u_n||\leq C$, now as $L^2$ is reflexive $\{u_n\}$ has a weakly convergent subsequence  $\{u_{n_{k}}\}$ i.e $\int_{0}^{1} u_{n_{k}} \rightarrow \int_{0}^{1} u $.So $Tu_{n_{k}}$ is convergent in $L^2(0,1)$. Thus compact.

Comment: If I have something like this: $(Tu)(x)=\int_0^1\cos(x^5+y^2)u(y)dy$. How I can study the same things? Do I have to integrate $\cos(x^5+y^2)$ or it's enough to show that it's bounded? For example knowing the $\cos(x)$ it's bounded by $-1$ and $1$

Comment: It's difficult to integrate such a function. So you should try to use the boundedness of $cos$ function.